# Can COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT be configured for DDEV

Tags: ddev

With a Blackfire service added to my DDEV project, I have been hitting docker-compose HTTP timeouts (which is new.)

```
Creating ddev-drupal-perf-workshop-db ...
Creating ddev-drupal-perf-workshop-blackfire ...

ERROR: for ddev-drupal-perf-workshop-blackfire  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

ERROR: for ddev-drupal-perf-workshop-db  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

ERROR: for blackfire  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

ERROR: for db  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).'
```

Is there a way to configure DDEV per-project to extend `COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT`? Everything is fine if I run `ddev start` again.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that whenever someone hits the timeout of COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT, it means that docker is broken. Please restart docker.

Note: He did restart Docker and that did seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: I run into the same issue, is there any way to prevent restarting docker … On bad days I have to restart docker many times. Nearly for each new ddev I start.

Answer (score 1):

Updating DDEV from version 17 to 18 fixed the problem for me.